# JSX element type (anything from react-konva) does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: typescript, react-konva

I'm using React with TypeScript and konva. After updating "@types/react" from "^17.0.39" to "^18.0.1" appears this error on every konva component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just update `react-konva` to the last version. It should work fine.